# How to find PMD Rulesets names in Gradle >2.0

Tags: java, gradle, pmd

In Gradle's Java projects we can use PMD via `pmd` plugin. To configure the rules which we want to use can do it in two ways:

- **ruleSetFiles** - The custom rule set files to be used. See the official documentation for how to author a rule set file. Example: ruleSetFiles = files("config/pmd/myRuleSet.xml")
- **ruleSets**The built-in rule sets to be used. See the official list of built-in rule sets.

With ruleSetFiles there is no problem you can find the names of the rules and to add or exclude ones, but in the documentation there is no information about the ruleStes? From where to find the exact names? From what I found from another projects the names are similar to the names from the PMD documentation but lower case. For example:

```
Braces - > java-braces
Clone - > java-clone
Implementation - >java-implementation
Code Size - > java-codesize
```

But this like **Security Code Guidelines** do not transform in *-> java-securitycodeguidelines* but just in **java-sunsecure**. I found that the names which works with PMD 5.1.1. are:

```
pmd {
      ruleSets = [
        'java-android',
        'java-basic',
        'java-braces',
        'java-clone',
        'java-codesize',
        'java-comments',
        'java-controversial',
        'java-coupling',
        'java-design',
        'java-empty',
        'java-finalizers',
        'java-imports',
        'java-j2ee',
        'java-javabeans',
        'java-junit',
        'java-logging-jakarta-commons',
        'java-logging-java',
        'java-migrating',
        'java-naming',
        'java-optimizations',
        'java-strictexception',
        'java-strings',
        'java-sunsecure',
        'java-typeresolution',
        'java-unnecessary',
        'java-unusedcode'           
        ]
    toolVersion = '5.1.1'
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

How to find mapping between PMD names which are shown in their documentation and Gradle names?

Comment: There is no mapping. These are the official PMD ruleset names.

Comment: So can you give me a link from where to find them because from the given link in the documentation 
http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.2/rules/index.html
I can't find them.

Comment: I don't know if and where the names are documented. Best ask the PMD folks.

Comment: I looked in their tests and find more rules names, but if the list is complete PMD folks have to give their last opinion.

Answer (score 3):

[The docs for RuleSetReferenceId](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/snapshot/apidocs/net/sourceforge/pmd/RuleSetReferenceId.html) are helpful, as is I believe this [directory](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/tree/master/pmd-java/src/main/resources/rulesets/java) in the source tree.  Basically put java- in front of any of these files to turn on the rules there.